# Is Python3 now available with Enthought Canopy Express?

Tags: enthought

Is Python3 now available with Enthought Canopy Express?. How to lookup the version of Python offered with Enthought Canopy Express at [Download Canopy](https://store.enthought.com/downloads/#default,)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A) Canopy 2.0 supports Python 3.5. It will be released around the end of December 2016.

B) Meanwhile, you can install Enthought Python 3.5 (command-line only) using [Enthought Deployment Manager (EDM)](https://support.enthought.com/hc/en-us/articles/217372346). This is the Python 3.5 version that Canopy 2.0 supports.

C) If you follow the first link on the download page ("Over 450 pre-built and tested Python packages"), it takes you to [this page](https://www.enthought.com/products/canopy/package-index/) which shows the current Python version 2.7.11.

Comment: Can you explain what is meant by "Meanwhile, you can install Enthought Python 3.5 (command-line only)", Does this mean that Python can only be used in the command line and if so Can the packages like NumPy, Pandas, SciPy be used with this command-line version and further then cannot Enthought Canopy IDE be used with Enthought Canopy Python 3.5 together with the packages NumPy, Pandas, SciPy, etc? –

Comment: Please read the link to the EDM documentation. Numpy, Pandas, Scipy, etc are already available for Enthought Python 3.5 via EDM.

Comment: Enthought Python 3.5 cannot be used in the Canopy 1.x GUI. It can be used with the Canopy 2.0 GUI, which will be released soon.